# Declare variable in js

Tags: javascript, html

I have a problem using quotation marks in js... 
I have an input field using this js-function

```
    function validate(xyz) {
            "+umum+" == "yeah_it_is_ok";
            if(xyz == ""+umum+"") {
                  alert("Hoera!");
                  return true;
            } else {
                  alert("Too bad!");
                  return false;
            }
     }
```

What do I have to insert in the input-field to get the `Hoera` message?$

In other words, what is the function of a `"` or a `+` in js?

Comment: What do you mean by "the input-field"?  Your question is not too clear.

Comment: Please read a JavaScript language reference. You clearly need to understand JavaScript basics. (And: try it! Use your JavaScript debugger/console which you should have - e.g. Web Console or Firebug in Firefox 4+, Developer Tools in Webkit browsers/IE)

Comment: and while you are at it (reading a javascript reference ) pay special attention to [rules for real identifier](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/webprog/jscript/ch02_07.htm)

Comment: @Chris Morgan, my JS debugger doesn't show any errors... But thanks for the links. I'll try it

Comment: @Michiel: I mean things like evaluating this in your console: `""+umum+""`, and `var umum = "foo"` followed by `""+umum+""`, and things like that. Use it to get interactive feedback on what it does. Experiment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have a syntax error in the function declaration,
but it will fail at execution time, because umum is not defined;
and surely you have a semantic error, because the only way to get "Hoera"
is to declare the umum var first and call the validate function later:

```
var umum;
validate("test value");
```

Of course, it always give a "too bad!" message unless you pass ""+undefined+""
as parameter. I think the right function should be:

```
function validate(xyz) {
        var umum = "yeah_it_is_ok"; // or whatever you want to validate with..
        if(xyz == umum) {
              alert("Hoera!");
              return true;
        } else {
              alert("Too bad!");
              return false;
        }
 }
```

In this case, when calling validate("yeah_it_is_ok") you'll get an "Hoera!".

Answer (score 2):

You would want to declare a variable like this:

```
var umum = "yeah_it_is_ok";
```

Note the `var` keyword and the use of a single equals for assignment.

Also, a pair of `"` characters is used to enclose a string variable, and the `+` will concatenate two strings. However, if you wish to have a double-quotation within a string you need to escape it with a backspace `\`. For example:

```
if(xyz == "\"+umum+\"") {
```

Comment: is the use of `var`obligated to declare a variable in js?

Comment: No, but it is recommended because if you omit `var` you will declare a global variable. See the `Declaring Variables` section in the MDN docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_Variables,_and_Literals

Comment: See my edits, I meant a string is enclosed in double quotes like so: `"mystring"`. Although a pair of single quotes may be used as well.

Comment: As others have said, you might want to read a beginner's JavaScript book to get familiar with the basics.

Answer (score 1):

Single- and double-quote characters are used to delimit string constants. The  `+` character is an operator that serves several purposes, including string concatenation, numeric addition, and asserting numeric "positiveness" (used often for its implicit side effects).

Comment: so what do I need to input in my input-field to get the `Hoera` message?

Comment: You still have not explained what you mean by "input-field".  The code you posted is so nonsensical that I have no idea what it is you're trying to do.

Comment: I have an input field with a button. Once a user clicks the button, the above js function is used to validate the input. But what do I need to input to get the `Hoera` message?

Comment: The code you posted **does not make any sense**.  You'll have to try and explain what it's supposed to do.  You also have not said how exactly your input element is related to this function.

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean to write your function like this.

```
function validate(xyz) {
    umum = "yeah_it_is_ok";

    if(xyz == umum) {
        alert("Hoera!");
        return true;
    } else {
        alert("Too bad!");
        return false;
    }
}
```

So then to answer your question, you can put the string that your looking for into the input-field. Which, since you don't have an input field in your example, we can just call the function with the correct string.

```
validate("yeah_it_is_ok");
```

Also it seems like you were thinking that you can use `"` or `+` in a variable. You can't do that. As others have suggested, you should learn the basics of JavaScript. w3schools.com and the Mozilla Developer Network are good places to do that.

http://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/learn/javascript

Answer (score 0):

I believe you put a \ infront of it
so like

```
    if(xyz == "\"+umum+\"") {
```